# Using Jade Templates (jade-lang.com) client-side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, template-engine, pug

I'd like to use Jade templates client-side. Preferably generated using the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline. I can't really figure out how to do this.

Anyone who've stumbled upon the same problem and found a great solution? Any thoughts are much appreciated.

- http://jade-lang.com/
- http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Check out http://railstech.com/2011/08/custom-pre-processor-in-rails-3-1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**P.S: Probably right now [Substack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623561/11926) is better.**

---

### browserify

Maybe you can use https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

> Browser-side require() for your node
>   modules and npm packages
>
> Just point a javascript file or two at
>   browserify and it will walk the AST to
>   read all your require()s recursively.
>   The resulting bundle has everything
>   you need, including pulling in
>   libraries you might have installed
>   using npm!

### Browser

http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/53 => The performance isn't that great according to this benchmark => http://gist.github.com/raw/550723/12d176698628e30a1df398c7ac7aea93924e1294/jade.js. But according to TJ it was never supposed to be used in the browser, but node.js instead. In that case it is going to be pretty fast. There are a lot of alternatives which you can use in the browser instead.

Comment: Great suggestion, god it working with plain Jade but this would have worked nice to. In addition it's a more broad solution, working for other node.js modules too!

Answer (score 31):

If you use [browserify](http://github.com/substack/node-browserify) you can use this handy jade middleware: [jadeify](https://github.com/substack/node-jadeify).
Then you can just call `jadeify("foo.jade", { x : 4, y : 5 })` browser-side after pointing a views directory at the middleware and you get back a jquery handle.

Answer (score 7):

Checkout [Blade](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade).  It is a Jade-like HTML template engine that is designed for client-side (and server-side) use.  There are some other features that you guys might like, as well.

**EDIT:** But, only for Node.js servers. There is no Ruby implementation at this time.

Answer (score 5):

This feature is now available in Jade.
http://jade-lang.com/api/

From their API Documentations:

```
var jade = require('jade');

// Compile jade file to a function
var fn = jade.compileClient('string of jade', options);

// Later in client site, render the function to HTML
var html = fn(locals);
```

You should pass the compiled javascript function to the client, for example by writing the function (fn in the example) to a .js file and then include the .js file in the html file with script tag.

Another option is using [templatizer](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/templatizer), which compiles jade to a .js file for you.

Comment: It's not obvious how you would compile a jade file on the server and then call the resulting function on the browser. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a gem called [tilt-jade](https://github.com/therabidbanana/) to do this within the asset pipeline. It's made to work exactly like EJS does with sprockets by default - it renders Jade templates down into functions so they can be called client side. I'm not sure it's a great solution, but it has worked okay for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Jade now supports compiling for the client by default; use the `-c --client` option. See http://jade-lang.com/command-line.

Answer (score 2):

I've just made a library for making jade available in client-side html. It is as simple as < jade>...< /jade>. Check it out: https://github.com/charlieamer/jade-query

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky but simple version for `browserify` using `gulp-jade`.

```
var jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('jade-client', function() {
    gulp.src('./views/**/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            client: true
        }))
        .pipe(replace(/function template/g, 'var jade = require("gulp-jade/node_modules/jade/lib/runtime");\n\nmodule.exports = function'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/templates'));
});
```

Then in my client side JS file...

```
var template = require('./path_to_compiled_template_file');
var renderedTemplateHtml = template({ aLocal: 'blah blah'});
```

So you only send to the client the specific templates you need and browserify makes sure you only have one copy of the runtime.