# adding jadeify to a node-express-browserify project

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, requirejs

## Context

I cloned a basic [node-browserify boilerplate project](https://github.com/raincole/node-template) and got it up. I'm using coffee-script. Right now, I'm trying to add [jadeify](https://github.com/substack/node-jadeify) to the equation as follows:

```
bundle = browserify
    entry: __dirname + "/app/init.coffee"
    debug: true
    mount: "/app.js"
bundle.use jadeify __dirname + '/views'
app.use bundle
```

This is before I even attempt to use jadeify anywhere.

## Issue

Everything works, until I add `bundle.use(jadeify(__dirname + '/views'))` as a middleware to browserify. Then I get the following error message in browser's console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __require is not defined
```

According to the browser's console, the source of this message is `/app.js`.

## Question

Why does this script fail with an error as soon as I try to add the jadeify middleware for browserify?

## Motivation

I figured that it'll be more convenient to reuse server-side jade templates on client-side, so I'm ditching underscore templates in favor of jade. While doing my research, I came across [this solution to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575743/using-jade-templates-jade-lang-com-client-side/6623561#6623561) that suggests the use of jadeify. It seems doable, but something seems to be failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can bypass jadeify by using browjadify

```
Usage:
   browjadify --entry=app.coffee >bundle.js
```

Source: browjadify

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var jade = require('jade')
var browserify = require('browserify')
var fs      = require('fs');
var argv = require("optimist").argv;

var b = browserify()

b.register('.jade', function(body) {
    var options = {"client": true, "compileDebug": false};
    body = "module.exports = " + jade.compile(body, options).toString() +";";
    return body;
});

var jaderuntime = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname+"/node_modules/jade/runtime.js", 'utf8');
b.prepend(jaderuntime); // Brings in var jade that jade.compile needs

b.addEntry(argv.entry); // gets browserify to do its thing

console.log(b.bundle()); // the bundled output
```

Comment: `{"client": true}` is what I was missing out when I tried this approach. This `.jade` handler for browserify is a decent lean substitute for jadeify.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this today as well and managed to fix it.

The problem for me was that jadeify depends on browserify version at most 1.2.9 but the current version of browserify in the git repo is newer (much newer, something above 1.8 if i remember correctly). And being new myself to working with this setup I installed browserify first (with the newest version) and then jadeify installed it's own dependent browserify (with the supproted version) in it's own module space.

Then when I was running my app the browserify I was calling was the new version but the libs that jadeify was using were the old version and this created a conflict somewhere and thus the error you were seeing as well.

I ended up just reinstalling the latest supported version of browserify in my app space and that fixed it.

LATER EDIT:

Problem with the fix above was that browserify@1.2.9 does not have caching and made reloading the server very slow. But I managed to find [browserijade](https://github.com/edmellum/browserijade) which works with the latest version of browserify (1.9.4) an does exactly the same things as jadeify.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issues with different version; this explains why the original setup wasn't working. 'browserijade' looks like a good substitute for now, but can possibly fall for a similar issue with future versions of browserify, hence the lean approach is preferred.

Comment: I agree but it looks like they'll be keeping it up to date and the same is true for any dependency resolution. But coming back to the main issue, I'm wondering if using browjadify provides the same functionality, most importantly dynamic referencing of partials.