# confusion between Jade and Handlebar

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

Trying out backbone+express with Jade as default templating.

Following a tutorial [here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/07/building-an-app-with-express-and-backbone-part-4/)(Great tutorial)

Confusion:

Many tutorials about backbone uses underscore template or handlebar to compile and render view.

I was using Jade as default template engine. My question is if I am using Jade then do I have to use another templating like Handlebar or underscore. If not how can I achieve following in Jade

```
render: function() {
  var template = $("#booktemplate").html();
  var compiled = Handlebars.compile(template);
  var html = compiled(this.model.attributes);
  this.$el.html(html);
  return this;
},
```

My assumption: I am thinking Jade and Handle bar both are templating system and can be used alternatively. Is it so?

Why not use both Jade & Handlebar? I dont want to use two different syntaxes

```
#{} from jade / {{}} from Handlebar
```

Comment: Yes. Thats what I want to do use one. But I cannot find out how to render this with jade. Somewhere I read I can do Jade client side with jade browser project and use Jade.compile() to compile. But this got me more confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Jade on the browser is not really a simple task. Thing is Jade is built for server side and does not support browsers.

This is why you'll often see people using two templates engines (if they use Jade). Some others are just gonna use Handlebars or Underscore everywhere - this is easier because templates engine working in the browser should work on the server. The other way around is not always true though.

Point to be taken here is that before starting to use a template engine, make sure it supports the environment you wish to target. There's plenty of options in term of engine, and this site can help you find one fittings your need: http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

If you're really like Jade, then, you can use a stack like [Browserify](http://github.com/substack/node-browserify) and some [middleware (Jadeify)](https://github.com/substack/node-jadeify) to make it work after pre-compilation. But you need to buy into the browserify concept and accept to precompile everything, everytime. You can check this related question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623561/1024223

Comment: BTW, just saw the lastest Jade version should work on recent browsers: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#browser-support Haven't tested it yet

Comment: Thank you Simon for clarifying confusion between server side templating and client side . Its just different things being used in tutorials, so sometimes thus confused. I checked jade browser support it says you have to still precompile and run with runtime.js. I will try handlebar now and will poke with other in future.