# What's the best way to use jade (template engine) with Jsp/Java projects

Tags: pug

I have just joined an existing project that uses jsp with html, I would like to use the Jade syntax, what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**jade4j**

I suppose you want to parse jade templates server-side, so you might want to have a look on [jade4j](https://github.com/neuland/jade4j) which does jade parsing/rendering through java - in its own words *fully compatible with the original jade syntax*.

**Update** as [Jade became pug](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html), jade4j became [pug4j](https://github.com/neuland/pug4j).

**client side?**

For client-side jade rendering (which has its own drawbacks) there are several options, mostly driven by the question how to achieve clean and structured require/include behavior. Some of them are discussed in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575743/using-jade-templates-jade-lang-com-client-side) e.g.